# How we can use CUR decomposition in place of SVD decomposition?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, svd

I have understood how [CUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUR_matrix_approximation) and [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) works, but not able to understand,

1. How we can use CUR in place of SVD decomposition?
2. Does C and R matrices in CUR follow the same properties as that of U and V matrices in SVD decomposition?

If we want to reduce the dimension of original matrix say from n to k, which matrix of CUR we can use to project original matrix, so that we will get k-dimensional data points.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a paper called [Finding Structure in Randomness](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061.pdf) that address some points about all of these decompositions as well as the SVD which would be covered in [Trefethan and Ba](http://bookstore.siam.org/ot50/)u .

1. The interpolative decomposition is used in different places. A paper that explores it is [here.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.8447.pdf)
2. The U,V are unitary matrices. C is a matrix containing a subset of the columns of A, R a subset of the rows.